# Adding debit or credit card programmatically into ApplePay

Tags: ios

if we have a credit or debit card information, could we add credit or debit card programmatically into Apple
Pay either from iOS app or server code?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no API to allow an application to manipulate the stored payment cards in the current Passkit framework.